# JavaFx resources (css) and OSGi

Tags: java, javafx, osgi

I have osgi (felix) javafx application. When launch application I get:

```
May 30, 2015 10:44:59 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css" not found.
May 30, 2015 10:44:59 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css" not found.
```

And my stages are without css rules (nor borders etc). The only solution I found is

```
Bundle systemBundle =FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MyApplication.class).getBundleContext().getBundle(0);
URL url0=systemBundle.getResource("com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css");
URL url1=systemBundle.getResource("com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena-no-transparency.css");
scene.getStylesheets().add(url0.toString());
scene.getStylesheets().add(url1.toString());
```

However it's bad solution and besides I need to do it for every stage. What is a better solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Try adding com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.modena to the package imports of your bundle.

Comment: @Arie van Wijngaarden I can' import such package as compiler says such package doesn't exist. Only package com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin exists.

Comment: I mean: add the package indicated to the "Import-Package" manifest header. It may not be a "real" Java package that contains Java code, it probably only contains resources.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Is was necessary to add packages to import section of manifest.mf. As I use maven it could be done via maven-bundle-plugin

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.7</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
       <instructions>
         <Import-Package>com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.modena,*</Import-Package>
       </instructions>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The most important is the asterisk sign at the end. It is necessary in order to add all auto detected packages this bundle needs. If we omit this sign then we will have to add all packages manually.